# Select to count collection?

Tags: c#, linq, list, select, collections

i have a "exampleClass", wich have a collection "exampleCollection".
if exampleClass.ExampleCollection.Count = 0, the exampleClass.ExampleCollection.Select(....
then that query will produce an error?

I'm working with c#, using linq
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing that?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you want to do with the results of that `Select(...)`.

Comment: No, it will result in an empty `IEnumerable<Something>`

Comment: You open yourself up to `NullReferenceExceptions` depending on `exampleClass's` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If `exampleClass.ExampleCollection.Count() == 0`, will `exampleClass.ExampleCollection.Select(....)` produce an error?

No, it will just produce an empty `IEnumerable<T>`.  `First()` and `Last()` will generate an error but not `Select()`.

If `exampleClass.ExampleCollection` is `null` then you *will* get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Don't forget `Single()`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will just receive an empty `IEnumerable<T>`, to be more specific an `WhereSelectListIterator<T, bool>`.

But it's interesting to note that if the collection was null, the error will be thrown but inside the **extension method** `Select`. The behavior is different, because the Select method is not a instance method of your collection, it's a extension method, like below:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector);
```

With extensions methods, your object is passed to a static method (the extension) as a parameter, so the NullRererenceException maybe or maybe not be thrown inside it (depends on the internal implementation). In the case of Select method,